# Error while adding plugin for firebase: Failed to fetch plugin https://github.com/jestcastro/cordova-plugin-firebase.git via registry

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, ionic3

I want to add Phone Authentication in Ionic with Firebase

Command :

```
ionic cordova plugin add https://github.com/jestcastro/cordova-plugin-firebase.git
```

Error

Failed to fetch plugin https://github.com/jestcastro/cordova-plugin-firebase.git via registry.

> cordova.cmd plugin add https://github.com/jestcastro/cordova-plugin-firebase.git
>    Failed to fetch plugin https://github.com/jestcastro/cordova-plugin-firebase.git via registry.
>         Probably this is either a connection problem, or plugin spec is incorrect.
>    Check your connection and plugin name/version/URL.
>   Error: npm: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
>   npm ERR! code ENOENT
>    npm ERR! syscall spawn git
>    npm ERR! path git
>   npm ERR!  errno ENOENT
>   npm ERR! enoent Error while executing:
>    npm ERR! enoent undefined ls-remote -h -t https://github.com/jestcastro/cordova-plugin-firebase.git
>    npm ERR! enoent
>   npm ERR! enoent
>   npm ERR! enoent spawn git ENOENT
>   npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
>   npm ERR! enoent
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
>   npm ERR! C:\Users\Varni 2\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2019-12-20T08_30_07_521Z-debug.log
>   [ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.
>
> cordova.cmd plugin add https://github.com/jestcastro/cordova-plugin-firebase.git exited with
>   exit code 1.
>
> Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.

Comment: Have you tried the answer?

Comment: Yes. Error  occur : Error: Cannot find module "@ionic-native/firebase".

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ionic-native/firebase do `npm install @ionic-native/firebase`

Comment: Please upvote the answer and mark it as correct since it helped you, thank you

Answer (score 0):

To add the plugin, execute the following command:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-firebase@0.1.24 --save
```

You can check the Github repo for more info:

https://github.com/jestcastro/cordova-plugin-firebase/blob/master/README.md#installation